# boost ptree access first element with no path name

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I am using boost library to manipulate a JSON string and I would like to access to a first element.

I was wondering if there where some convenient way to access a first element of ptree with no path name.

I do this, but I got no value :

```
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;
pt::ptree pt2;
string json = "\"ok\"";
istringstream is(json);
try
{
        pt::read_json(is, pt2);
        cout << pt2.get_child("").equal_range("").first->first.data() << endl;
}
catch (std::exception const& e)
{
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
}
```

**Solution:**

replace `cout << pt2.get_child("").equal_range("").first->first.data() << endl;`

by `cout << pt2.get_value<std::string>() << endl;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Property Tree is **not** a JSON library.

Secondly, the input is **not** in the subset of JSON supported by the library ([e.g.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/305241ef2b1caaa5)).

Thirdly, since the input results in a tree that has **no** child nodes, you should use the value of the root node itself.

Lastly, if you **had** wanted the first node, use `ordered_begin()->second`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb3f5074b16d9b98)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void broken_input() {
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    std::istringstream is("\"ok\"");
    read_json(is, pt);
    std::cout << "Root value is " << pt.get_value<std::string>() << std::endl;
}

void normal_tree() {
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    pt.put("first", "hello");
    pt.put("second", "world");
    pt.put("third", "bye");

    std::cout << pt.ordered_begin()->second.get_value<std::string>() << std::endl;

    write_json(std::cout, pt);
}


int main() {
    try {
        broken_input();
        normal_tree();
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Root value is ok
hello
{
    "first": "hello",
    "second": "world",
    "third": "bye"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to access to a first element.

It is impossible in general case, since JSON elements are not place-fixed by definition. The current first element can change its place after JSON transformations and a resulting JSON will be the same, although elements are reordered. Thus such API is not provided by BOOST.

Comment: OK, but is it possible in my example to get string value? (eg. `"ok"`)

Comment: IMHO "ok" is a strange JSON. I am not sure `pt::read_json` can read it. Use a debugger to see what `pt2` contains after read.

Comment: `pt::read_json` read it. In debugger  `(jsonResponse)._M_string_length` is equal to `4`

Comment: simplissime, solution is `cout << pt2.get_value<std::string>() << endl;`

Comment: That elements are not positional/ordered in JSON is utterly irrelevant for Boost Propery Tree, as properties _are_ ordered in property trees.